# Green reputation badges on Summary page have black text

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

There has been change in style for reputation badges on Profile Summary page which makes text harder to read.

What used to be white text on green background has changed into black text on green background.

[image: Screenshot of style change showing the problem with new colors]

If there is a problem with readability in previous style, I suggest using darker green would be more appropriate choice.

If I remember correctly, few years back the green color for reputation badges used to be a bit darker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**: A fix has been shipped to production.

---

Thanks for reporting! This is a bug introduced in our latest Stacks update.

I have a [fix en route](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/1197) that will restore the white text on the green background and will update this answer when it's shipped to production.

Comment: Possibly related, [bounties don't have blue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384296/).