# Bounty badges drained of colour

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties

Something I noticed just now (look inside the circle):

[image: Bounty notice]

The badge with the bounty amount in a bounty notice was previously white text on a blue background; now it has the same colours as the notice behind it.  Given that the badge text is still visibly offset relative to the baseline as before, this doesn’t look like an intentional decision to remove formatting.

(Another bug I noticed is already covered at [Green reputation badges on Summary page have black text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384261/), so I edited that part out.)

Clearing the cache did not help.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: A fix has been shipped to production.

---

Yep, that `+50` is a badge and should be rendered as white text on a blue background.

This bug was introduced when updating our core codebase to [Stacks v1.5.0](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases/tag/v1.5.0), which refactored `.s-badge`  component's CSS to require the base `.s-badge` class when using any modifier classes. The bug reported shows the modifier class `.s-badge__bounty` being applied without it's base `.s-badge` class.

I'll be submitting a fix for this today and I'll update this answer when it ships to production. Thanks for reporting this @user3840170!

Comment: One day later (well, you did write "today"), any updates? Has something blocked the fix?

Comment: "today" referred to when I submitted the fix for review, but it took some time to get that ✅ to ship it out. Anyways, it's out now!